# Access LXC Container using Ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

I'm using Ansible to manage the LXC containers (still learning to do so). I'm stuck while trying to run some task inside the LXC. I tried to use the [lxc connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/lxc.html) but no luck so far.

Goal: 
ansible ==> ssh ==> vm / barematel ==> ansible connection plugin (lxc) ==> container => run some tasks

Ansible Version

```
2.5.1
```

Hosts

```
[default]
staging-host ansible_ssh_host=10.10.10.104 ansible_ssh_user=root
```

Testing Playbook:

```
- name: Create a Container
  lxc_container:
    name: "{{ container_name }}"
    container_log: true
    template: ubuntu
    state: started
    template_options: --release bionic

- name: Add Dynamic Host
  add_host:
    name: "{{ container_name }}"
    ansible_connection: lxc
    remote_addr: "{{ container_name }}"

- name: Try to access the container
  delegate_to: "{{ container_name }}"
  shell: uname -a
```

Output

```
task path: /media/ansible/roles/ha_lxc/tasks/haproxy.yml:39
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py
<ha-lb-1> THIS IS A LOCAL LXC DIR
fatal: [staging-host]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "ha-lb-1 is not running"
}
  to retry, use: --limit @/media/ansible/ha.retry
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
staging-host                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I'm trying to solve this since last 3 days but no luck. I would really appreciate the suggestion, tips, help.

Comment: Maybe you could share your answers if you found them ...here on StackOverflow too :)